# Using "any" function in groovy always return the result of the last item closure

Tags: groovy, closures, any

I'm trying something like the following :

```
"""foo
bar""".eachLine { line ->
    ['foo', 'baz'].any{
        println(it + ' - ' + line)
        line == it
    }
}
```

result is :

```
foo - foo
foo - bar
baz - bar
false
```

I would like to test if any of the lines of the multiline string

```
"""foo
bar"""
```

is present in the array `['foo', 'baz']`.

But here it returns false event if `foo` is present in the string.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
"""foo
bar""".split('\\n').any { line -> ['foo', 'baz'].contains(line)}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this:

```
 def multiLine = ("""foo
bar""")
List lines = multiLine.split("\n") as List
def lookingFor = ['foo','baz']

if (lookingFor.intersect(lines).size() > 0) {
        println "true"
        return true
}
```

Comment: But I need a single boolean result and I guess this won't return only once as "any" could do. The println statement is only here for debug, what I really need is to know weather or not any of the lines string in the multiline string are present in the strings array. Any tips ? Why my "any" function is not returning true and stops the first time the closure is equal to true ?

Comment: On your use of the any,  you're running each line of the multiline through the any, so you may have the true - but the last line is the value thats going to be returned.  Unless you had set a state variable or did a return when you found the first match.